# sending email with symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, email, swiftmailer

I'm trying to create a function that gives the opportunity for every user to send an email for another user. This is the basic controller of Swiftmailer:

```
public function contactAction($id)
{
$enquiry = new Enquiry();
$form = $this->createForm(new EnquiryType(), $enquiry);
$from=$this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getemail();
$em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$user=$em->getRepository('PfeUserBundle:User')->findBy(array('id'=>$id));       
$request = $this->getRequest();
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
 $form->bind($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
          $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Intello')
            ->setFrom($from)
            ->setTo($user->getemail())
            ->setBody($this->renderView('PfeUserBundle:Contact:contactEmail.txt.twig', array('enquiry' => $enquiry)));
        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('blogger-notice','Ton message a été envoyé avec succès');
            // Redirect - This is important to prevent users re-posting
            // the form if they refresh the page
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('pfe_intello_contact_mail'));
        }
    }
```

i have this error 
Error: Call to a member function getemail() on a non-object

Comment: you need to set smtp protocol and password

Comment: What do you mean by update? And what have you tried already? Did you read the docs?

Comment: @StephanVierkan I want that any user can send an email to another user, but with this function all the emails sent arrive to the email already configured in the parameters. yml

Comment: Did you read the documentation? Symfony is very well-documented: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/email.html

Comment: Here's an example: https://github.com/dancostinel/symfony-email. Read it carefully, as its not well formatted!

Comment: @DanCostinel thanks a lot but I have another problem  look up

Comment: @StephanVierkant I changed my function and I have a new error can you help me ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$user isn't an object because you are getting an array.

Change:
$user=$em->getRepository('PfeUserBundle:User')->findBy(array('id'=>$id));

Into:
$user=$em->getRepository('PfeUserBundle:User')->findOneBy(array('id'=>$id));

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with sending the email

Comment: you saved my life @Ralph